# mean and variance of the SDE $dy_{t}=\nu(\mu-y_{t})dt+J_{t}dN_{t}\sigma dW_{t}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Say I have an SDE as follows:

$$dy_{t}=\theta(\mu-y_{t})dt+J_{t}dN_{t}\sigma dW_{t} \tag{1}$$

where dW is a standard Wiener process and dN is a Poisson process with arrival rate $\lambda$.

How do I then find the mean and the variance? If possible at all?

As the Wiener process is multiplied with the jump I am not sure how to start using stochastic calculus. One idea is to log everything so I can treat each component individually, but am not sure that would work.

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Where did you get this from? Are you sure you copied correctly?

Comment: It is correct :-) also called "jump-drift", e.g. http://agaillard.eu/resources/aiyagari2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment, but I am not among the privileged, so I answer:

Do you think that summing a product involving one (stochastic) differential with another product involving two (stochastic) differentials yields a well-defined expression?

Comment: I suspect it does not :-) But am not well versed enough in stochastic calculus to know if it is possible.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that, too. By the parantheses (those around "stochastic") I wanted to express that I would struggle with resolving such expression already in the non-stochastic case.

Comment: I would like to comment above, but, still, I am haunted by unprivilegism:

Above, you referred to http://agaillard.eu/resources/aiyagari2.pdf as a source for this equation, but to me the equation seems to not actually appear in that source.

Comment: See under "income process". He writes epsilon - N(0,sig^2) rather than the Weiner process

Comment: I would say that you might have translated this $\varepsilon$ falsely to your above formula.

Comment: I think you are right. So in principle, should just be a normal pdf. In that case, would it make sense to derive analytically to you? Or still be a mess